# How to roll back a spring jpa repo.save() function

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've seen several different posts regarding this topic, but most of them tend to be that it's not working. What I'm trying to do is save several objects in a loop, but if one of them fails -> rollback all of the saved objects.

Here is my current code.

```
@Override
public Fleet saveFleet(String fleetId, List<String> serialNoList) {

    fleet = new Fleet();
    Fleet tempFleet = new Fleet();
    fleet.setKey(new FleetKey());

    //Change this to string utils uppercase
    fleet.getKey().setFleetId(StringUtils.upperCase(fleetId));
    fleet.getKey().setUserId(StringUtils.upperCase(userService.getCurrentUser().getUserId()));
    fleet.getKey().setDealerCd("USER");

    for (int i = 0; i < serialNoList.size(); i++) {
        //Try catch block?

           tempFleet = fleetRepo.save(fleet);
       }
    //commit if all the data goes correctly, rollback if there is an exception. 
    return tempFleet;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have mentioned you can use @Transactional:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html

> What it actually does is:

```
try { 
   transaction.begin(); 
   saveFleet(fleetId, serialNoList);
   transaction.commit(); 
} catch(Exception ex) { 
   transaction.rollback(); 
   throw ex; 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)` to the top of the method. Spring will rollback all data within this transaction for you if any exception is thrown by database.

Answer (score 2):

You can use @Transactional  annotation to rollback transaction in case of exception.